# phpseclib absolute path upload

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

When I try to upload file using full path like:

```
$sftp->put('/home/user/data/data.csv', 'Hello world');
```

then upload failed.
However when I change a directory before file upload it's working fine:

```
$sftp->chdir('/home/user/data');
$sftp->put('data.csv', 'Hello world');
```

Do I have to always call **chdir()** before upload a file or there is some kind a flag in phpseclib settings?

Comment: How does the upload fail? Can you be more specific? What is `$sftp->pwd()` before and after the `chdir`? What SFTP/SSH server is that?

Comment: Can you provide the SSH2 logs? You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` at the top and `echo $sftp->getLog()` after the `$sftp->put()`. Once you have them post them on pastebin.com and edit your post to include the link. And then reply to your post saying that you've done that. Thanks!

Comment: @neubert Logs says "No such file /home/user/data/data.csv" therefore I have to always call chdir().

Comment: @Martin Prikryl before / and after /home/user/data. Server ProFTPd with SFTP mod.

Comment: Your code works for me against OpenSSH SFTP server. And I do not see a reason it should not work against other servers.

Comment: Can you post the full logs?

Comment: @Martin It does work, but only when chdir() is called before upload. My question was "do I have to call chdir() everytime before put()"

Comment: I was referring to your code with the absolute path (as that what the question is about).